# how to set the font with mailx?

Tags: unix-shell

Solaris Korn Shell

I am writing sql reports to an oracle database, spooling them to a file and emailing them with mailx. I use the syntax below. The reports do not format properly, unless I use the Courier New font. How do I set this with mailx?

mailx -s "MY REPORT, `date +'%D %r` " -r "REPORTING SYSTEM" me@me.com< /mydir/mysql.log > /dev/null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a font in plain text email (which mailx is sending).  You need to configure your client software to use the right font.

Comment: could you elaborate on how to do this?